# Why is my custom .d.ts not working? LeaderLine is not a constructor

Tags: angular, .d.ts

I want to add typings to the leader-line library, but I keep getting the error TypeError: leader_line_1.LeaderLine is not a constructor

I am sure it's just one small thing / concept I am overlooking or not understanding and I am going nuts over it.

Here is a stackblitz of my approach: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leader-line-ovnz2v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Here is the original stackblitz with the untyped LeaderLine:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leader-line?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: stackblitz has problems running scripts from `angular.json` sometimes, so I am including the script tag in the index.html to make the stackblitz work!

I checked your code, ignoring the part where you want to import the types the difference between the two stackblitz is that you are missing the entry in `scripts` array for `leader-line`, that might be the issue!

angular.json

```
        ...
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/leader-line/leader-line.min.js"
        ]
        ...
```

or

```
<!-- <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93690/leader-line.min.js"></script> -->
<my-app>loading</my-app>
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leader-line/1.0.3/leader-line.min.js"
  integrity="sha512-aFBNsI3+D6ObLLtyKwdZPZzDbcCC6+Bh+2UNV8HC0R95BpcBT+dmmZ5NMpJi/Ic8uO0W7FGcg33IfuHg+7Ryew=="
  crossorigin="anonymous"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
></script>
```

After that change the import like

why we do this is because you are declaring a variable and a type with the same name `LeaderLine` so to differentiate between the two I am renaming the type using `as LeaderLineType` and then setting the type to the property `LeaderLine`!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LeaderLine as LeaderLineType } from 'leader-line';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

declare var LeaderLine: typeof LeaderLineType;
```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leader-line-ejtck9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Findex.html)

Comment: This does not solve the error for me.
You have to click one item of each list (depening on screen resolution top&bottom or left&right), this should draw a line between those items. But in the first link I provided (the one with the custom .d.ts) this does not working because said error is thrown.
In this stackblitz I already import LeaderLine like you said it should be done.
For the animOptions part, I just commented out the usage of it.

Comment: No, that doesn't fix the issue either.
You can just test your assumptions in the stackblitz. That's why I provided it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to work.

Can you explain why the detour of importing it as LeaderLineType and declaring it in the .ts file again is needed?

Comment: Why is it not enough to just rename the namespace to something unique? I would prefer to avoid the need of another declare everytime I import LeaderLine somewhere.

Comment: @Tucaen if leader line was a import you will not have this problem, but since its declared as a `var` property, the type is not inferred, so you need to do this extra step! anyway you have to define the type of the var property through an import only, if you want postfix it with `LeaderLineType` on the `.d.ts` so that you do not have to rename it! Also try without the renaming, maybe it works even then! I did not check that!